# Change Facebook photo album post date

Tags: facebook

How can you change dates on a photo album to be in the past on the timeline format?  I know how to add a picture to the wall in a time, but I need to change albums.

Answer (score 2):

Go to album from http://www.facebook.com/YOUR_USERNAME/photos

Select edit album

[image: Edit Album]

Select edit date

[image: Edit Date]

After setting, go back to your timeline on that date and the album should now be there